# PostgreSQL insert into and select from an array of user defined objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been having some issues while trying to learn PostgreSQL. I've created a relational object called person and then a table consisting of a primary integer key and an array of person objects. I have a feeling it's the way I am inserting rows into this array however, I am unsure of how to access specific columns of the object as well (Ex. person.name).

Currently the only way I was able to insert a row is as follows however, I think it may just be making a string object instead of the proper person object.

```
INSERT INTO towns VALUES (0, '{"(bob,blue,springfield,33)"}');
```

For reference the schema I created is:

```
CREATE TYPE person AS (
    name text,
    favorite_color text,
    hometown text,
    age integer
);

CREATE TABLE towns (
    town_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    people person[]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the reasons I prefer the `array[...]` syntax over `'{...}'`. You don't need to think about nesting quotes:

```
INSERT INTO towns  (town_id, people)
  VALUES 
(0, array[('bob','blue','springfield',33)::person]);
```

`('bob','blue','springfield',33)::person` creates a record of type `person` and `array[...]` that makes that a single element array. You have to cast the anonymous record created with `(...)` to person to make this work. If you want to insert multiple person records into the array it's a bit less typing to case the whole array at the end:

```
array[('bob','blue','springfield',33), ('arthur','red','sleepytown',42)]::person[]
```

To select a specific element of a record in an array, you can use e.g:

```
select town_id, people[1].name
from towns
```

Answer (score 0):

You are combining 2 things here, a field type as `array` of a composite type `person`.

To insert a composite type you should do something like this `ROW("bob","blue","springfield",33)`, note that `ROW` keyword is optional

For array types you should use brackets inside single quotes, like `'{val1,val2}'`, in your case, you are adding only one element of the `array`, which result is a `person` type.

Your example should look like:

```
INSERT INTO towns VALUES (0, '{ROW("bob","blue","springfield",33)}');
```

Note that the double quotes are for values inside the `person` type, not for the whole object.

References: [Composite Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/rowtypes.html),  [Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/arrays.html)

To access the person value, you have to wrap the `object` in `()`, so `(person).name`

Comment: Gotcha, I appreciate the demystification of quote and single quote! I tried executing the example given however, the error `malformed array literal: "{ROW("bob","blue","springfield",33)}"` is raised. I did some testing after reading the docs you posted more thoroughly, using a table with just an instance of the composite type. With the structure you mentioned for inserting into a composite type and wrapping the fields to access composite fields works perfectly!

Comment: Note that the array should be wrapped in single quotes, not double

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was by inserting in the following way:

```
INSERT INTO towns VALUES (0, (array[ROW('bob','blue','springfield',33)::person]));
```

And to select you would have to do this:

```
select (people[1]).age from towns;
```